# Can anyone identify this uniform from SE Asia?

Tags: world-war-one, identification, uniform, south-east-asia

Can someone identify this uniform? I suspect it is from WW1 and was taken by an Australian photographer.. tho obviously not in Australia. It is part of a bigger historic pic.. a glass plate amongst a collection of plates which were shot around 1910-20

[image: CROPPED IMAGE OF A MILITARY COURT IN SE ASIA - WW1 POSSIBLLY]

I have added a 2nd image of another person present also in uniform
[image: 2nd soldier type] 
[image: Unknown Asian image]

Comment: Can you provide the entire image?

Comment: The entire image is disturbing to some. There is a prostrate prisoner and two seated (crossed legged) males in religious garb (like Buddhist wrap) they are surrounded by villagers and there are two soldiers in this same uniform.

Comment: I see. Perhaps this clip will do then.

Comment: I added a 2nd image from the background that might help... different uniform

Comment: Tough to tell from a grainy B&W, but if it were me I'd start looking in the area of [Melanesia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/Oceania_UN_Geoscheme_-_Map_of_Melanesia.svg/640px-Oceania_UN_Geoscheme_-_Map_of_Melanesia.svg.png) (The islands north of Australia from New Guinea to Fiji), although if those really were Buddhists, Indonesia might be a better bet. Melanesia is heavily Christian.

Comment: New Guinea was part of Aus' back then and given the nicker-boker type pants it has to be tropical Asia. There is another Caucasian face in the crowd and I also added a cut of one of the wrapped images. It would be good to solve it all ... thanks for your help.

Comment: My guess is Burma, mostly because of the monk. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-31937266

Comment: Uniforms look British inspired but without the complete picture showing the clothing of the locals it's a bit hit and miss. Just provide a link to the picture so the fainthearted can avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Looks Burmese, military police uniform. Person in white uniform maybe be a servant? The monk is holding a palm leaf prayer book ( Pali )

Comment: It would improve the answer if you could expand on what makes you believe this is a Burmese military police uniform.

Comment: @Linda Graham: Not likely. The rank is corporal. Very few corporals have servants.

Comment: @Jos: How do you know that statement applies to Burmese corporals of the relevant time period? Have you read [**Burmese Days**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burmese_Days) by George Orwell, where IIRC he has a servant even though a just lowly police constable in Burma.